# sys.maxint and xmlrpclib.MAXINT

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I guess there is a reason for xmlrpclib to have a seperate MAXINT than sys. Can anyone explain to me why?

```
>>> print xmlrpclib.MAXINT
2147483647
>>> print sys.maxint
2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the maximum integer `xmlrpclib` can support can be different from the maximum integer the system can support.

```
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
>>> xmlrpclib.MAXINT
2147483647L
```